# How to create a new column in a Spark DataFrame based on a second DataFrame (Java)?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark DataFrames where one of them has two cols, id and Tag. A second DataFrame has an id col, but missing the Tag. The first Dataframe is essentially a dictionary, each id appears once, while in the second DataFrame and id may appear several times. What I need is to create a new col in the second DataFrame that has the Tag as a function of the id in each row (in the second DataFrame). I think this can be done by converting to RDDs first ..etc, but I thought there must be a more elegant way using DataFrames (in Java). Example: given a **df1 Row-> id: 0, Tag: "A"**, a **df2 Row1-> id: 0, Tag: null**, a **df2 Row2-> id: 0, Tag: "B"**, I need to create a Tag col in the resulting DataFrame df3 equal to df1(id=0) = "A" IF df2 Tag was null, but keep original Tag if not null => resulting in **df3 Row1-> id: 0, Tag: "A"**, **df3 Row2-> id: 0, Tag: "B"**. Hope the example is clear.

```
|   ID  |   No.   |  Tag  | new Tag Col |
|    1  |  10002  |   A   |      A      |
|    2  |  10003  |   B   |      B      | 
|    1  |  10004  | null  |      A      |
|    2  |  10005  | null  |      B      |
```

Comment: Any reason why a simple `LEFT OUTER JOIN` won't work for you?

Comment: I edited the question and will look into LOJ..

Comment: LOJ doesn't completely solve it, but I think if I follow it with a udf() then I get what I need. Thanks,

Comment: If it is not enough you can try to update the question with example input and expected output. It is really hard to understand what you want right now.

Comment: when Tag is null, new Tag = Tag(id). E.g. Tag(id=1) = A, so we assign A to 10004 and Tag(id=2) = B to 10005. I think I need a udf() for this.

Comment: It is still not very clear. If you try to match on ID what happens if there is a conflict. And is it a single DF? In your description there were two RDDs with one being lookup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103635/discussion-between-kai-and-zero323).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need here is left outer join and `coalesce`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.coalesce

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 10002, Some("A")), (2, 10003, Some("B")),
  (1, 10004, None), (2, 10005, None)
)).toDF("id", "no", "tag")

val lookup = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "A"), (2, "B")
)).toDF("id", "tag")


df.join(lookup, df.col("id").equalTo(lookup.col("id")), "leftouter")
  .withColumn("new_tag", coalesce(df.col("tag"), lookup.col("tag")))
```

This should almost identical to Java version.

Comment: This is not working in Java. its expecting Seq<Columns>.. Any help here???